# What does youtube playlist views count represent?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Recently I found out that my youtube playlist with songs [[link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2Zq2tniXpa0LZ9pWNJUahPcm0eSzU4Bv)] somehow has 6k+ views. Given this playlist was even hard to find using search box on friends' devices, number seems  bit unreal. So I wonder what is this number:

- does it count my own and/or anybody's views more than once

  - if yes, which is the limit per user if there is any
  - is it once/limited per account, per ip, or something else
- is number incremented on playlist opening, on opening one more song or other options.

Research (i.e. googling) left me with a bunch of contradictory info.